# How to detect when emacs is started with `--debug-init`?

Tags: config

I'd like to turn some things off normally and then re-enable them when emacs is started with `--debug-init`. For example, I get loads of warnings about the length of doc-strings in packages. I want to suppress these warnings normally, but I'd like to be able to see wall these warnings when I am in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most directly:

```el
(when init-file-debug
  (message "--debug-init"))
```

as the `--debug-init` argument results in `(setq init-file-debug t)`

Or more indirectly:

```el
(when (eq debug-on-error 'startup)
  (message "--debug-init"))
```

as `startup` is the value given when `(eq init-file-debug t)`

(I'd go with the first option, though.)

Answer (score 0):

I looked at <kbd>C-h describe-variable</kbd> and was able to find the variable `debug-on-error`. This might be an even better option than just a variable which signifies that the `--debug-init` argument was called, as this is a non-nil whenever emacs is set to enter debugger on an error signal, and not just if a specific CLI argument is called.

This something to the effect of

```
(if debug-on-error
    (foo)
    (bar))
```

Should do the trick to run `foo` when the `debug-on-error` is `t` and run `bar` otherwise.

If you only want this to work when `--debug-init` is called look check @phils solution instead.

Comment: In my tests, `--debug-init` had already been removed from `command-line-args` by the time custom init code was executed, so that wasn't a viable method of detection.

Comment: Thanks for that catch, I've updated that portion to point to your answer!